# Running the lynx text web browser inside emacs

Tags: emacs, lynx

Lynx is a pretty cool text browser. How to launch it from emacs?

My current approach is `Mx shell`, then `lynx`. But it prompts me for my terminal type (which I don't know - I use terminal and GUI Emacs on GNOME). The default option makes the output barely readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWebBrowser) page on the emacswiki. I use `emacs-w3m` which works with `w3m` and can be configured to use the `lynx` bindings. There is also `emacs-xwidgets`, it's not stable but it mostly works.

However if you really want to use `lynx` you can try with <kbd>M-x</kbd>`term`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: or `ansi-term` for colour support.

Comment: @phils: I don't know the differences between `term` and `ansi-term` but that's not the colour support, they can both display colours. (in emacs24).

Comment: Ah, interesting. Specifically I've always thought that you needed to be running `ansi-term` in order to be able to use `(ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)`, but I've no idea whether I've always been wrong, or if Emacs 24 makes the two modes more alike than they used to be, or if we're just talking about different kinds of colour support :)

Comment: @phils: I've looked at the code and they are both part of `term.el` and both seem to support `ansi-term-color-vector`. Anyway, it works and emacs rules.

Answer (score 4):

Given that the accepted answer is able to solve the problem, an off-the-shelf solution does exist, which is also mentioned by @phils in the comment

1. `M-x ansi-term`
2. At the prompt “Run program:”, instead of the default `/bin/sh`, enter `lynx` instead.
3. Do whatever legitimate within lynx, such as pressing `g` and then entering a URL

Reference: [Term And Lynx @ EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TermAndLynx)

Or you can try to use web browsers built in emacs, such as [eww](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/eww), which in my opinion provides better compatibility than Lynx does.

Answer (score 1):

After googling for a while I found this [nero-el](http://code.google.com/p/nero-el/). Seems no development is being done now.